# C# - error while sending email from outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook, scheduled-tasks

I have a C# exe which sends email from Outlook, it works fine if run manually.

I am trying to run it through Task scheduler but it gives following error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
at sendMail.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Recovered\Root\Projects\sendMail\sendMail\Program.cs:line 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a hack. I could fix the exception but it was sending emails as Microsoft does not allow COM objects to operate through a service (in my case Task Scheduler).

I created a script and triggered command from it every few hours as needed, since it was running as a program and not a service, it works fine, the only disadvantage being sleep calls invoked from my script.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [manual](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870655) provides this:

> Cause:  If many COM+ applications run under different user accounts
>   that are specified in the This User property, the computer cannot
>   allocate memory to create a new desktop heap for the new user.
>   Therefore, the process cannot start.
>
> WORKAROUND: To work around this problem, modify the value of the
>   following registry subkey:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
>   Manager\SubSystems\Windows

Comment: change the value to what?

Comment: the manual instructs to add extra 512 in sharedsection but my current values are: SharedSection=1024,20480,768

Comment: And do you have an issue adding 512 as well?

Comment: i have increased non-interactive heap size from 768 to 2048, will let you know if that works, thanks for your time

Comment: The idea is to change the 512 to 2048. The manual assumes there are only 2 entries (from old code maybe?) reference this which shows what each number correlates to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/desktop-heap-limitation-out-of-memory @DevharshTrivedi

Answer (score 1):

Outlook is a singleton - COM system will refuse to marshal calls between two processes running in different security contexts.

Comment: Outlook cannot be used from a service (such as the Task Scheduler). If you are using the Outlook Object Model, and Outlook is already running, there is nothing you can really do.

Comment: I tried doing this but it didn't work:

    System.Diagnostics.Process[] processes =    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK");
                int collCount = processes.Length;

                Application app;

                if (collCount != 0)
                    app = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Application;
                else
                    app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

It fixed exceptions but emails are not sent.